# Improve responsiveness of $(...).click on touch interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I need access to a web-based on screen keyboard which will be used on a touch interface.
[This](http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/378_jqueryKeyboard/demo/index.html) example looks nice and functional, however when I try it on an iPad, the responsiveness it very low IMHO. It's not comfortable to use and sometimes whole words are misspelled due to slow response.

Is there a way to improve the experience on this type of on screen keyboard? This implementation uses the $('#id').click(...); function to process the events. Is there a better way to achieve the goal of typing on the screen? Are there better plugins out there?

Note: The final application will run on different types of devices. For several reasons, native on screen keyboards are no option.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile browsers (iOS specifically, but others too) have a slight delay before triggering the 'click' event so it can differentiate between a single tap and a double tap.

For that style of keyboard you could probably get away with changing the 'click' to a 'mouseup'/'touchend' listener to remove the delay.

However, be aware that you would need to put in extra work if you need to make sure that you only handle a touch/click event if the user presses and releases on the same element (instead of starting the touch on one element and the sliding to another one before releasing).

Comment: You can use [this little plugin](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) to do pretty much what you describe.